# Dune2 tag synomyms

Tags: support, status-completed, tag-synonyms

Some confusion arose while tagging [this](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/318329/how-do-i-kill-the-sandworm) question. The game in question was called "Dune: The Battle for Arrakis" on Genesis/Mega drive, "Dune II: Battle for Arrakis" on PC in Europe, and purportedly "Dune II: The Building of a Dynasty" on PC elsewhere*. We already have a [dune2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dune2) tag, and a well meaning community member created a [dune-the-battle-for-arrakis](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dune-the-battle-for-arrakis) tag. Can we get the new tag made into a synonym for the old, please?

<sub>* anecdotally, I verified that I have Dune II: Battle for Arrakis in the Chicago suburbs, and my father impulse bought the game because he's a fan of the books. I can't imagine he wandered into a game import shop in the early '90s on a whim.</sub>

Comment: I think I somehow ended up making *dune-the-battle-for-arrakis* while I was trying to tag the question, but the stackexchange system wouldn't let me post a question with a new tag I just made

Comment: It was confusing at first. Why let me create the tag if I can't use it? Or if I can end up creating the tag, why not let me use it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay so I've gone ahead and done the following:

- Renamed [dune2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dune2) to [dune-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dune-2) for consistency with other tags

Created synonyms for:

- [dune2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dune2) -> [dune-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dune-2)
- [dune-the-building-of-a-dynasty](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dune-the-building-of-a-dynasty) -> [dune-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dune-2)
- [dune-the-battle-for-arrakis](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dune-the-battle-for-arrakis) -> [dune-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dune-2)
- [dune-2-the-building-of-a-dynasty](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dune-2-the-building-of-a-dynasty) -> [dune-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dune-2)
- [dune-2-the-battle-for-arrakis](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dune-2-the-battle-for-arrakis) -> [dune-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dune-2)

This should avoid any confusion in the future, and make it easier for all users to find questions related to the game. Might seem a bit overkill, but according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dune_II) this game can be referred to by all of these titles, save Dune: The Building of a Dynasty, which I added in for the sake of completion.